# The compatibility level of the target schema 150 is not supported

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Sitecore 10. I am getting the below error.

```
The compatibility level of the target schema 150 is not supported
```

can you please help? given below is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Which version of MSSQL are you running?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred because, my previous installation failed.

The previous installation had created few DBs with the Sitecore Prefix name provided during installation. that was the cause of error.

I deleted all the DBs created by prefix name, and re-run the installer, it worked. The installation was successful.